# Reverse order of integration ∫∫ f(x, y)dydx + ∫∫ f(x, y) dydx

Tags: integration

Consider the integrals
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2x} f(x, y) dy dx + \int_{1}^{2} \int_{0}^{4x-2x^2}f(x, y) dydx.
\end{equation}

I am trying to reverse the order of integration. For the first integral I got $x$ limits as $0$ to $y/2$, and $y$ limits as $0$ to $2$. For the second integral I got $x$ limits as $-2x$ to $1$, and $y$ limits as $0$ to $2$. I don't think this is correct, can someone help me find the correct limits, particularly for the second integral?

Comment: I always recommend drawing the region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the region of integration of the first integral is a triangle:

$A = (0,0), B = (1,0), C = (1,2) \to I_1 = \displaystyle \int_{0}^2 \int_{y/2}^1 f(x,y)dxdy$

For the second one: $y = 4x-2x^2 = -2(x-1)^2+2\to (x-1)^2 = \dfrac{2-y}{2}\to x =  \sqrt{\dfrac{2-y}{2}}+1$.

$I_2  = \displaystyle \int_{0}^2 \int_{1}^{1+\sqrt{\frac{2-y}{2}}}f(x,y)dxdy$.

Notice that the graph of $y = 4x-2x^2$ has a vertex at $(1,2)$ which is the maximum of $y$,hence the limits of integration.

Comment: hi, could you explain the y/2 to 1 please?

Comment: You travel from the curve $x = y/2$ to the curve $x = 1$.